# Python evaluates the program without error, sum and average are correct but the product is always the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to figure out why my program will run and what to fix so that the portion where the multiplication happens would give me the product of all the numbers a user would enter.

```
flag = False
rNum = 0
num = ''
sum = 0
product = 1
count = 0
temp = input("Please enter your numbers separated by a space, Press the 
Enter Key when finished >> ")

for i in range(len(temp)):
if temp[i] != ' ':
    if temp[i] == '-':
        flag = True
    else:
        num += temp[i]
if temp[i] != ' ':
   def multiply(rNum):
    total = 1
    for i in range(0, len(n)):
        total *= [i]
        product *= rNum
if i == len(temp) - 1 or temp[i] == ' ':
    rNum = int(num)
    if flag == True:
        sum -= rNum
    else:
        sum += rNum
    flag = False
    count += 1
    num = ''

    print ("sum: %d product: %d average: %d" %(sum, product, sum/count))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `python -m pdb <your filename here.py>` or inserting `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` statements to use the [python debugger, pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to figure out what's going on?  Alternatively, have you tried inserting `print` statements to see values?  You are being downvoted because you are not telling us what you've tried.

Comment: "not evaluating properly" is not a useful problem description. What were you trying to do, and what visibly goes wrong? If you get an error message, post it, including stack trace, code-formatted. If you get wrong output, post it, as well as the exact output you expected to get, code-formatted.

Comment: @ChazingtonPerk you define the `multiply` function but you don't use it or call it `multiply()` anywhere in your code, so when you print `product` it never get updated from `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read the tutorials in more detail as you are making the task too complicated. This code might give you an idea of the how the task might be achieved.

```
text = input("Please enter your numbers separated by a space,\nPress the Enter Key when finished >> ")

# if you want to split a text string at whitespace use split()

text_numbers = text.split()

# then if you want to convert the text to a number

numbers = [float(i) for i in text_numbers]    

# to add the numbers together use sum()

total = sum(numbers)

# to find the product and keeping the method obvious
product = 1
for i in numbers :
    if i != 0 :
        product *= i

# the number of numbers can be found from the length of the list, len()

average = total/len(numbers)

print ("total: %.3f product: %.3f average: %.3f" % (total, product, average))
```